# Screen Burn In on Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

My question is simple. I have screen burn in on my Galaxy S7 Edge. Will replacing the screen get rid of the issue or do I need to fix something else, too?

Comment: Replacement of screen is best. There are apps that claim to repair but that's a hoax

Comment: And get it done by authorised folks

Comment: It's not just the way out; it's the *only* way out.